# PHP get properties method in super class

Tags: php, oop

I want my classes to inherit a getProperties method from its superclass.

```
class Mother {
  function getProperties(){
    return get_class_vars(get_class($this));
  } 
}

class Child extends Mother{
  private $one = 1;
  private $two = 2;
}
```

Problem is that if I call getProperties on Child, I get an empty result:

```
 $c = new Child();
 var_dump( $c->getProperties() );
```

returns `array(0) {}`

If I overwrite the getProperties method in Child with the same command, it works as expected and returns `array(2) { ["one"]=> int(1) ["two"]=> int(2) }`. So I figure that `$this` is resolved to the Mother class and not to the class that inherited the method.
How can I get Child to inherit the method in a way that it works like I need it to? Or how I change the scope of `$this` to work with Child instead of Mother?
Maybe I'm just missing pretty simple fact here so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your properties are `private`. That makes them accessible only and exclusively to the declaring class, none other. Make them `protected`.

Note though that even then there seem to be some inconsistencies among different PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/1Rm6e

Comment: was writing the same thing ;) +1

Comment: Ah ok, this works, thanks. I thought that the method and the properties would be in the same scope and therefore _see_ each other.

Comment: @ximarin No, `private` really means *private to this class*. :)